# a recipe condition that will run only if a recipe from a specific cookbook is not present

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I want to have a condition block in my recipe that will be true if there is no recipe from a cookbook named "frenchblog" in that node's runlist.

I have found the following [link](https://gist.github.com/kwilczynski/c271f251ea7f48ba99b3): that suggests to use `node.run_list.recipe?("frenchblog::default")`. Only that this will work for specific recipes and not the entire cookbook, and I can't find a way to match is against a regex (like `/frenchblog/`) because it's not a string and I can't convert it to one.

How can I test for the presence of a recipe from a cookbook within a recipe's code? Anyway to convert the objects in `node.run_list` to strings so I can match them to a regex?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very weird request and there is a very high chance you are doing something you shouldn't but: `node["recipes"].any? {|r| r.start_with?("frenchblog") }`

Answer (score 0):

The `node.run_list` method return an array, you can use all ruby function to filter it and check presence.

Something along the line of this should do:

```
node.run_list.select { |entry| entry[/frenchblog::/] }.length == 0
```

This sounds like something very strange to do and it's probably brittle at the end of the day.